# Weird Nautilus / Unity look

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus

I don't know what it caused this weird behavior of Nautilus, but here are some screenshots to demonstrate why it is looking weird:

[image: desktop_screenshot]

**Icon size is so big and it can not be reduced.**

[image: File_Manager_screenshot]

**No options, weird buttons style, big list size with no options to reduce it.**

And I'm sure this is the default theme.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? That is definitely not the default theme.

Comment: That is not the stock nautilus in 16.04 for ubuntu session, either you're using  gnome-shell, a ppa, 16.10, or something else. The menu  for  icon size *could*  be in the dropdown in middle right icon.  Maybe post `apt-cache policy nautilus` & `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Comment: here is the result http://imgur.com/KuxtS6q

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [Budgie Remix PPA](https://launchpad.net/~budgie-remix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). You can remove it with:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:budgie-remix/ppa
```

This will

- remove the PPA from the repository list,
- replace all packages from the PPA with the next best package from any other remaining configured repository if one is available and
- remove all other packages installed from the PPA.

You'll probably need to start a new desktop session (log out and back in) for the changes to take effect fully and without glitches.

---

For more info and alternative methods to remove PPAs see [How can PPAs be removed?](/q/307/175814)